# Macro for mapping integer to string for token

Tags: c++, macros

I need a macro `TAG(N,C)` which takes to arguments `N` and `C` generates a token of the form TAG_ + f(N) + g(C), where `f(1) = A`, `f(2) = AB`, `f(3) = ABC`, `f(4) = ABCD` and `g(0) = (empty string)`, `g(1) = _FOO`, `g(2) = _BAR`.

Examples:

```
TAG(3,0) -> TAG_ABC
TAG(2,1) -> TAG_AB_FOO
TAG(4,2) -> TAG_ABCD_BAR
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Something like this ? `#define TAG(N, C) TAG_##f(N)##g(C)`

Comment: @naab: And how would `f(N)` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following:

```
#define f_1 A
#define f_2 AB
#define f_3 ABC
#define f(N) f_##N

#define g_0 /* Empty */
#define g_1 _FOO
#define g_2 _BAR
#define g(N) g_##N

#define CONCAT3_(A, B, C) A ## B ## C
#define CONCAT3(A, B, C) CONCAT3_(A, B, C)
#define TAG(N, C) CONCAT3(TAG_, f(N), g(C))
```

Comment: What is the purpos of using `CONCAT3` and `CONCAT3_`?

Comment: Those "indirections" are to allow some substitutions, else you obtain `TAG_f(N)g(C)`