# Find correct macro constant in constexpr function of template class

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, constexpr

There is a C header with a very long list of macro constants like this:

```
#define MODE_1_A 101
#define MODE_1_AB 21
#define MODE_1_ABC 9901
#define MODE_2_A 1031
#define MODE_2_AB 347
#define MODE_2_ABC 692
...
```

While the macro names follow a very regular pattern, unfortunately there is no way to reliable compute the constant.

I would like to write a template class which can return the correct mode integer as a `constexpr`.

```
template<unsigned C, unsigned M>
struct MyClass
{
   constexpr int mode() {
      // C = 1 & M == 1 => return MODE_1_A
      // C = 1 & M == 2 => return MODE_1_AB
      // and so on
   }
   ... // a lot of additional code
};
```

What is the best way to write the `constexpr` function `mode`?

Comment: Use the conditional operator.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: For a lot of constants this might get messy...

Comment: In case you haven't noticed, this is already messy.

Comment: You also have no choice. You can't hack around with macros using templates or `constexpr`. The best you can do is concatenate.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: So what about posting an answer how you would do it? I would be interested.

Comment: @Danvil: Honestly, I think ecatmur has the best solution you're going to get. Code generation ftw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may specialize the method :

```
template<unsigned C, unsigned M>
struct MyClass
{
   static constexpr int mode();
};

template<> constexpr int MyClass<1, 1>::mode() { return 101; }
template<> constexpr int MyClass<1, 2>::mode() { return 21; }
```

And with `TAG(N, C)` from [Macro for mapping integer to string for token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031541/macro-for-mapping-integer-to-string-for-token):

```
#define DEFINE_MODE(N,C) \
    template<> constexpr int MyClass<N, C>::mode() { return TAG(N, C); }

DEFINE_MODE(1, 1)
DEFINE_MODE(1, 2)
DEFINE_MODE(2, 1)
// ...
```

Comment: Ah, I did not know you could do that :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the preprocessor!  Using the [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) library:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(n) \
    template<> struct MyClass<n, 1> { \
        constexpr int mode() { return BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_CAT(MODE_, n), _A); } }; \
    template<> struct MyClass<n, 2> { \
        constexpr int mode() { return BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_CAT(MODE_, n), _AB); } }; \
    template<> struct MyClass<n, 3> { \
        constexpr int mode() { return BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_CAT(MODE_, n), _ABC); } }; \
#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_LIMITS (1, 10)
#include BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE()
```

Comment: There is a lot of additional code in `MyClass`. With your approach this would need to be duplicated ...

Comment: @Danvil that's easy, just move the mapping into its own template and call it from `MyClass::mode()`.

Comment: Yes you could do that.

Answer (score -1):

You could stick with a macro :

```
#define MODE(a,b) MODE_##a##_##b
```

Then use it like this :

```
std::cout << MODE(2,ABC) << std::endl;
```

Your question miss an information on how to stitch an integer M to the strings A, AB, ABC… Also, does C and M always know at compile time or may be variable parameter to some outer function ?

Comment: `MyClass` is a template!

Comment: @Danvil, `MyClass` Looks like [a Y solution to a X problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Do not ask about Y but ask about X.

Comment: I do not see how this applies. My problem is clearly stated in the question.